# Spring batch (seq. pagingReading->other pagingReading)

Tags: pagination, spring-batch, chunks

Is the following possible with Spring Batch?

1. I'm get paged data from remote rest service,  using DepartmentItemReader extends AbstractPagingItemReader for this. It's return ids of departments
2. For every record from chunk (from step 1), need get paging employees by department id from remote rest employees service.

How to do it right?

add listener to reader on step 1 and make request to employees service inside it?
other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the driving query pattern: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders.

The idea is to enrich items in an item processor. In your case, the reader returns department IDs, and the item processor fetches employees for the current department by ID.

Comment: Thank you for responce. For perfomance, i'm put rest request to writer. But it no fast operation, and now i'm get new problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77243253/spring-batch-connection-closed-when-long-time-step-execution