# Spring batch. Connection closed when long time step execution

Tags: spring, exception, spring-batch, hikaricp

I'm have job with several steps (step0, step1, step2). Connection pool - Hikari, max-lifetime 30 minutes. Database - Postgres
Step1 is long time. If execution time more then 30 minutes (may be 1 hour, 3 hour),   i'm get exception:

```
'2023-10-05 13:34:29,566 ERROR [http-nio-8097-exec-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Application exception overridden by rollback exception 
 org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [UPDATE dhs_sout.BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT
SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ?
WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?
.....
.....
.....
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:502)'.
```

Config of step1:

```
 return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
            .<UUID, UUID>chunk(employeeTmpProcessorPageSize, transactionManager)
            .reader(employeeTmpReader)
            .writer(employeeTmpWriter)
            .faultTolerant()
            .skipLimit(step1SkipLimit)
            .skip(RuntimeException.class)
            .allowStartIfComplete(true)
            .listener(new SPItemProcessorListener())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
            .build();
```

I'm think about increase max-lifetime, but it n good idea.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Batch cannot prevent the connection from being closed by the database server if it exceeds the timeout.

Therefore, if the step might take more than the max timeout of the database connection, then you need to increase the timeout (or better, try to optimize the performance of the step if possible).

Comment: Thank you for responce. It's Spring batch pitfall ) . May be exist way to change Sring batch behavior for except hold connection for batch meta tables?

Comment: The job repository used by Spring Batch is based on a given pre-configured datasource (that you configure yourself as needed). There is no parameter in Spring Batch for connection timeouts (this is a parameter related to the datasource itself).

Comment: Thank you for responce. I'm found solutions. But it's no good solutions) 1) using ResourcelessTransactionManager for steps and JobRepositoryFactoryBean 2) using in memory DB for JobRepository.